# Bootstrap dropdown menu getting hidden behind the dhtmlx layout

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, dhtmlx

I am using a DHTMLX 3T layout, in which topmost layout(a) has the bootstrap components(Drop down, search box, etc).

When I click on the dropdown, the menu is getting hidden behind the other layout(c) and I am unable to see the menu list. Can you let me know the solution for this problem so that i can see the menu items.
I have tried to set the z-index for the drop down but still unable to resolve the issue.

[image: Click to see the image showing the issue]

Comment: check your divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bootstrap menu is attached to the layout cell and designed so that it is not available to show it outside the current container.
You may only try to create your menu outside of the layout cell.